# How to select Radio button using JQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have created group of radio buttons using `<c:forEach>` tag. I have given ids also.

On click of any radio button i do a ajax call. Once i come back to that page i want to re select that radio button.

For this i assign back selected radio button ID to a hidden text box.

My question is how to make radio button selected with this hidden text box value.

I tried like

```
$('input[id="$("#myHiddenTextBoxId").val()"]').attr('checked', true);
```

But it is not working. Here myHiddenTextBoxId hold value of previously selected radio button.

Answer (score 3):

You where sending it all as a string - you need to split it out

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[id="' + $("#myHiddenTextBoxId").val() + '"]').prop('checked',true);
});
```

`prop()` should be used as of jQuery 1.6 -> http://api.jquery.com/prop/

**Note** Also ensure that your code is enclosed within the `$(document).ready()` function to ensure that the DOM is ready before trying to manipulate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input[id="' + $("#myHiddenTextBoxId").val() + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

You cannot have a jquery function call (`$("#myHiddenTextBoxId").val()`) in the selector string.

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/yr5aq/).

---

**Note**:

Use .attr() this way: `.attr('checked', 'checked')`
Although, for special attributes like checked or disabled, use `.prop('checked', true)` (jquery 1.6+)

Comment: HI @Didier G I tried your solution but it did not work. It gives java script error. I tried with .prop()

Comment: Well, my solution works ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/yr5aq/)). Is the ID saved in your hidden field correct ?

Comment: Does your radio button exists in the DOM when you try to re-select it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myHiddenTextBoxId').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: @DidierG.: You may be right, but I did not see the HTML that OP referred to.